# qregexp extract all numbers from string

Tags: regex, qt, qt4, qregexp

I'm quite noob with regular expression, all i want to do is to get all numbers from a string.

```
QRegExp rx;
rx.setPattern("\\d+");
rx.indexIn("this string contains number 123 and 567*872");
QStringList MyList = rx.capturedTexts();
```

**Expected result is**: 123 and 567 and 872.
**What i get is**: 123

Comment: Something like this, split the string at nonnumbers, join the array with space, trim string (in javascript): `let s = 'this 123 and 567*872'; s.split(/[^\d]+/).join(' ').trim();//832 832 222`

Comment: @Rafael qregexp. That never works.

Comment: @revo yeah, that's why it's not an answer :) just a *comment*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get all matches with a loop like

```
QRegExp rx("\\d+");
QString str = ""this string contains number 123 and 567*872"";
QStringList MyList;
int pos = 0;

while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
    MyList << rx.cap(0);
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

Here, `rx.cap(0)` accesses Group 0, the whole match. The [`QRegExp::indexIn`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#indexIn) *attempts to find a match in* *`str`* *from position* *`offset`* *(`0` by default). If offset is `-1`, the search starts at the last character; if `-2`, at the next to last character; etc*. While the position is not `-1`, we may iterate through all the matches in the string.